# C# Image from Database to DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I am really new to C#, so I have a lot of problems. I have a Windows Form with a SQL Database and I want to see the picture that I have saved with the rest of the data in the `PictureBox` and `TextBoxes` when I select for example `user 1` in the `DataGridVie`. I know what my problem is but not how to fix it.

```
void Load_table()
{
    try
    {
        string myConnectionstring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;  username=root;password=root";
        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionstring);
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idBenutzerdaten, name, vorname, straße, hausnr, plz, wohnort, telenr, personr, schlossnr, picture FROM testdb.benutzerdaten;", myConnection);
        MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
        myDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
        BindingSource mySource = new BindingSource();
        mySource.DataSource = myDataTable;
        dataGridView.DataSource = mySource;
        myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception fehler)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Es gibt ein Problem mit der Datenbank\n" + fehler.Message, "Datenbankfehler ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

This is the code to get the Data from the Database to the `DataGridView`. When I want to get the saved image as well, I get an error. I know that I have to change the column to an image column or something like that, but nothing I found so far worked out for me.

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel.Enabled = false;
    DataGridViewCell cell = null;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dataGridView.SelectedCells)
    {
        cell = selectedCell;
        break;
    }
    if (cell != null)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
        tbx_id.Text         = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        tbx_name.Text       = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        tbx_vorname.Text    = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        tbx_strasse.Text    = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        tbx_hausnr.Text     = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        tbx_plz.Text        = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        tbx_wohnort.Text    = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        tbx_telenr.Text     = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        tbx_perso.Text      = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        tbx_schlossnr.Text  = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

The event from the datagridview. Not sure what and how to add here. But must be something like

```
imagebox.image = row.Cell[10].Value.Image();
```

I guess the problem is that the rows of the datagridview come 1 to 1 from the database, and I should create them manually, but then I got even more errors.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using blob to store the images? just cast it

```
imagebox.image =  byteArrayToImage(row.Cell[10].Value));
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: Hello an thanks, this should work for the 2nd problem, but when i login in to the database from my 1 form and go to 2nd the Void load_table causes an error -> http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160126/ahwdbzq7.jpg or i got your answer wrong is the code from you for the void Load_table() ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Your Problem is that you are not casting to get the propertype
try this :

```
imagebox.image = ((DataGridViewImageColumn)row.Cell[10]).Image(); 
// or try this :
imagebox.image = (Image)row.Cell[10].Value;
```

if you don't have any other problem with your code those should work with you